# Node js permanently locale changes

Tags: node.js, internationalization

I'm using Expressjs and i18n for my node js application to manage the multilanguage.

Here is my  i18n configuration :

**i18n.js**

```
var i18n = require('i18n');

i18n.configure({

  locales:['en', 'fr'],

  directory: __dirname + '/../locales',

  defaultLocale: 'en',

  cookie: 'lang',
});

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  i18n.init(req, res);
  res.locals.__= res.__;

  var current_locale = i18n.getLocale();

  return next();
};
```

**server.js**

```
var i18n = require('./configs/i18n');
 ...

app.use(i18n);
```

Actually if I want to change the locale settings I have to do that for each routes :

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res){
    res.setLocale('fr')

    res.render('pages/index');
});
```

It is possible to use `setLocale()` once and it will permanently change the locale ?

And what is the best practice ? Should I specify the language inside my routes everytime ? E.g :

```
app.get('/:locale/index', function(req, res){
    res.setLocale(req.params.locale)

    res.render('pages/index');
});

app.get('/:locale/anotherroute', function(req, res){
    res.setLocale(req.params.locale)

    res.render('pages/anotherroute');
});
```

Or I have to store the locale in my database for each user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**middlewares**](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to avoid the repetition (place this code before your router) :

```
// Fixed locale
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setLocale('fr');
  next();
});

// Locale get by URL parameters
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.params && req.params.locale){
      res.setLocale(req.params.locale);
  }
  next();
});
```

Personally, I prefer to store the local setting in database, it avoids to weighing the request with not necessary data.

**Another solution** is to set the language with HTTP headers [`Content-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language) and [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept-Language.3a_header) and get it with [`req.acceptsLanguage()`](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#req.acceptsLanguages).

Comment: Thanks for your answser. I get Cannot read property 'locale' of undefined ? Doest it mean than I should specify the locale param for each routes ?`app.get('/:locale/index', function(req, res)`

Comment: I update the post, I fix the bug and I add a better solution based on HTTP headers and `acceptsLanguage()` function. I hope it answers to your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if I want to store the language in my database I just have to do a mongoDB query inside your fixed locale middlware function or get it with my passportJS user session variable ?

Comment: Exactly ! I think that getting the locale at login and stock it in `req.session` is a good idea.

Comment: Ok nice. Thank you for your help